# Search txt file for string where middle substring is unkown

Tags: c++, string, variables

New to C++ and I am trying to search through a file to find a specific line with information. However the information might be shown in different units and therefore I am wondering if there is a clever way to do this.

```
 weight_measurements.txt


    //calculations of total vehicle weight above 
    The vehicle's weight is:            1 ton.
    The vehicle's weight is:         1000 kg.
    The vehicle's weight is:     220.4262 lbs.
```

The goal is to search through the file with ca a thousand lines. Find the line which says:

```
 "The vehicle's weight is:       xxxxx  kg.
```

And then save the value "xxxxx  kg.".

Is there any way to do this in one go? Or should I search for a line with "The vehicle's weight is:" store all the string who do in an array and then sort out the one with the correct unit?

The line number where the information keeps changing depending on the depth of the calculations above, so using iistream::getline() is not a good solution.

Comment: try with this regex on rubular.com - [0-9]{1,}(\.){0,1}[0-9]{0,}

Comment: You can parse the file using Boost.Spirit - it will be fast and robust.

Comment: *using istream::getline() is not a good solution*. Maybe, but I still think that `std::string::getline` and then search in each line as a std::string is probably the way to go...

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Issue with the regex is all numbers get stored, and there are numbers in the calculations too. And I do not find "xxxxx  kg.", but the "xxxxx" through the entire file.

Comment: @froffen - can you post some more sample data and expected output. If you haven;t solved the problem already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue through

```
while(getline(myReadFile, output))
{

    if(output.find(line_looking_for) != std::string::npos
    {
        // clean string if neccesarry
    }    
}
```

I was lucky enough that the measurement I was looking for was always the 'ton' (in my example code), therefore I didnt have to save all the outputs who started with the line I was looking for. And then sort them based on the measurements.

However I would we prob done that with `output.find(measurement)`